# soap client in php - looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, xml, soap

I get the error message : "looks like we got no XML document" .

This is my php script :

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://ws-argos.cls.fr/argosDws/services/DixService?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0));

$result = $client->getXml(array (
        'username' => 'my username',
        'password' => 'my password',
        'platformId' => '1',
        'nbPassByPtt' => 100,
        'nbDaysFromNow' => 10,
        'mostRecentPassages' => true
    ));


echo "====== REQUEST HEADERS =====" . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    echo "========= REQUEST ==========" . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
    echo "========= RESPONSE =========" . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($result);
```

and this is the result of __getLastRequest() :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://service.dataxmldistribution.argos.cls.fr/types">

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:xmlRequest>
            <ns1:username>my username</ns1:username>
            <ns1:password>my password</ns1:password>
            <ns1:platformId>1</ns1:platformId>
            <ns1:nbPassByPtt>100</ns1:nbPassByPtt>
            <ns1:nbDaysFromNow>10</ns1:nbDaysFromNow>
            <ns1:mostRecentPassages>true</ns1:mostRecentPassages>
        </ns1:xmlRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and this is how the request should look according to the documentation :

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope”
    xmlns:typ=”http://service.dataxmldistribution.argos.cls.fr/types”>

   <soap:Header/>

    <soap:Body>
      <typ:xmlRequest>
        <typ:username>mturiot</typ:username>
        <typ:password>qt</typ:password>
        <typ:platformId>1</typ:platformId>
        <typ:nbPassByPtt>2</typ:nbPassByPtt>
        <typ:nbDaysFromNow>10</typ:nbDaysFromNow>
        <typ:mostRecentPassages>true</typ:mostRecentPassages>
        </typ:xmlRequest>
    </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

What am i doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You could override __doRequest, something [like this](http://moxune.com/blog/2011/09/debug-soap-server-zend-studio/).  That would let you inspect the raw HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, I turned to get solution in a different way. 
It might not be the best way, but it works.

Source for the solution [found here](https://www.mikemackintosh.com/fixing-soap-exception-no-xml/)

```
$param = array(
'username'=>$username,
'password'=>$password,
'platformId'=>$platformId,
'nbDaysFromNow'=>20
);

$client = new SoapClient("http://ws-argos.cls.fr/argosDws/services/DixService?wsdl", 
array('trace' => 1, 
"exceptions" => 0, 
'style'=> SOAP_DOCUMENT,
'use'=> SOAP_LITERAL));
$results = $client->getXml($param);

$results = $client->__getLastResponse();
//Handle BOM
$xml = explode("\r\n", $results);
//The resultant CDATA is at 6th tag
$response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $xml[6] );

//Get the CDATA content alone
$explode1 = explode("<return>", $response);
$xmlVar = explode("</return>", $explode1[1]);


$finalXML = $xmlVar[0];

//Convert string as XML
$xmlElem = simplexml_load_string('<xml>'  . $finalXML . '</xml>');
echo $xmlElem;
```